# Google collab pip doesn't get recent package version

Tags: google-colaboratory, pypi

I'm using Goggle colab to test code that I maintain in PyPI. However, the runtime environment does not recognize the existence of recent versions of my package. I see that there is an environment variable LAST_FORCED_REBUILD, which has a date that is several days ago. Perhaps I need a more recent rebuild? It used to be possible to do a "Factory reset" from the "Runtime" menu, but that is not present. I've tried all the reset options, but that date remains.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'disconnect and delete runtime' option. It does the same thing as far as I'm aware. The factory reset option has been removed and/or renamed.

Comment: No help. To be more specific, I want to test new versions of my PyPI package "wtlike". On the web, or my local machine, I see that the latest one is 0.4.0. Yet running pip on the colab runtime, it only shows up to 0.3.10. I had guessed that the LAST_FORCED_REBUILD date had something to do with it, freezing the versions as of that date. The disconnect and delete runtime did not change that, however.